Add string to CSV via PSCustomObject
Currently trying to figure out how to export a string to a CSV file. I'm working on a larger script, and I'm putting together a mini test script to figure this part out. I know how to get PowerShell to add entries to a CSV using PSCustomObject, what I can't figure out is how to get PowerShell to add a specific string entry (such as "valid" or "this is incorrect"). What I have right now looks like this:
$CSVLog = New-Item "\\file path\Logs\$(Get-Date -f yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss) Test Log.csv" -ItemType File -Force

$CSVLog.Add(
  [PSCustomObject]@{
    'Column 1' = [string]::"Test" #Yeah, didn't think it would be this simple, but had to try...
  }
)

Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation -Path $CSVLog -Append

Of course, what I'm doing right now only throws out an error in the Host. What do I have to do in the "Test" portion to make this work?

It is even simpler than you expected, just create an object using the pscustomobject accelerator and then pipe it to Export-Csv, which already knows how to convert objects to Csv:
[PSCustomObject]@{ 'Column 1' = 'Test' } |
    Export-Csv "\\file path\Logs\$(Get-Date -f yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss) Test Log.csv" -NoTypeInformation

